# Trezor driver not loading

Tags: trezor

This morning I opened my brand new Trezor and plugged it into my laptop. The message I received was that the device was not installed correctly or something like that. I tried three times. Then I installed the Trezor plugin for Chrome and now the laptop doesn't recognize the device at all - no message, nothing. The device screen still lights up with its welcome message.
What should I do?